# R code help to calculate an index of cell value by column

Tags: r

I am new to r and i am trying to calculate a index from a given table.I have calculated minimum, maximum, and median of coulnmn of the table below.I have some NaN in the column. The first and second column are latitude and longitude, and from 3 onwards its a soil moisture.

```
1            2       3      4        5       6       7        8      9       10       11
28.188  -111.438    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
28.188  -111.312    362.74  360.723 361.645 356.894 354.188 354.166 355.16  350.148 339.705
28.188  -111.188    189.991 188.153 188.96  184.49  182.028 181.776 182.322 175.402 161.836
28.188  -111.062    312.743 310.278 310.867 306.436 304.178 304.157 306.149 302.238 293.318
28.188  -110.938    146.97  144.582 145.274 141.367 139.66  140.137 142.949 141.15  135.776
28.188  -110.812    149.095 146.86  147.706 143.991 142.258 143.005 146.508 144.388 138.771
28.188  -110.688    147.06  144.825 145.479 141.687 139.826 140.714 144.882 142.481 136.582
28.188  -110.562    145.857 143.75  144.493 140.791 138.866 139.933 144.882 142.148 135.532
28.188  -110.438    135.207 133.254 134.163 130.436 128.345 129.526 135.307 132.01  123.974
```

I used following code to calculate the mimimum, median, and maximum;

```
 data=read.table('NLDAS_MOISTURE_200CM.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',') 
    df=data.frame(data[3:11]) 
    Minimum=apply(X = df, MARGIN=2, FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE) 
    Maximum=apply(X = df, MARGIN=2, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE) 
    Median=apply(X = df, MARGIN=2, FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now , i want to calculate an index of each cell column wise using the following conditions :

> 1) if cell value of a column is smaller than the median of the column
>   (cell value< Median)    Index=  (cell
>   value-Median)/(Median-Minimum)*100
>
> 2) if cell value of a column is greater than the median of the column
>   (cell value> Median)   Index=(cell value-Median)/(Maximum-Median)*100

I would appreciate if some body can complete the code using either if or for loop. Thanks

Juvin

Comment: It sounds a bit like, given that you know the calculations, `apply` and the logical conditions, then you just need the `which` function.

Comment: @Juvin Have you tried the `lapply` `Map` solutions I posted below?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df[-(1:2)] <-  lapply(df[,-(1:2)], function(x) {med <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)
                    min1 <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
                   max1 <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE)
                  ifelse(x <= med, 100*(x-med)/(med-min1),
                                    100*(x-med)/(max1-med)) })

df[1:5]
#     X1       X2           X3          X4           X5
#1 28.188 -111.438           NA          NA           NA
#2 28.188 -111.312  100.0000000  100.000000  100.0000000
#3 28.188 -111.188   19.5253013   19.690246   19.7010032
#4 28.188 -111.062   76.7090200   76.524161   76.3880913
#5 28.188 -110.938   -8.6049493  -10.013107  -10.6078282
#6 28.188 -110.812    0.4739999    0.473519    0.5177805
#7 28.188 -110.688   -7.9056758   -8.082774   -8.9585261
#8 28.188 -110.562  -17.2526320  -16.622314  -16.8912667
#9 28.188 -110.438 -100.0000000 -100.000000 -100.0000000
```

Or based on the already calculated `Minimum`, `Maximum`, `Median` values

```
df[-(1:2)] <-  Map(function(v, w, x,y) ifelse(v<=w, 100*(v-w)/(w-x),
                  100*(v-w)/(y-w))  ,df[-(1:2)], Median, Minimum, Maximum)
```

For calculating `min`, `max`, `median`, other option would be to use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(min=min(., na.rm=TRUE),
          max=max(., na.rm=TRUE), median=median(., na.rm=TRUE)), 3:11)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(28.188, 28.188, 28.188, 28.188, 28.188, 
28.188, 28.188, 28.188, 28.188), X2 = c(-111.438, -111.312, -111.188, 
 -111.062, -110.938, -110.812, -110.688, -110.562, -110.438), 
X3 = c(NaN, 362.74, 189.991, 312.743, 146.97, 149.095, 147.06, 
145.857, 135.207), X4 = c(NaN, 360.723, 188.153, 310.278, 
144.582, 146.86, 144.825, 143.75, 133.254), X5 = c(NaN, 361.645, 
188.96, 310.867, 145.274, 147.706, 145.479, 144.493, 134.163
), X6 = c(NaN, 356.894, 184.49, 306.436, 141.367, 143.991, 
141.687, 140.791, 130.436), X7 = c(NaN, 354.188, 182.028, 
304.178, 139.66, 142.258, 139.826, 138.866, 128.345), X8 = c(NaN, 
354.166, 181.776, 304.157, 140.137, 143.005, 140.714, 139.933, 
129.526), X9 = c(NaN, 355.16, 182.322, 306.149, 142.949, 
146.508, 144.882, 144.882, 135.307), X10 = c(NaN, 350.148, 
175.402, 302.238, 141.15, 144.388, 142.481, 142.148, 132.01
), X11 = c(NaN, 339.705, 161.836, 293.318, 135.776, 138.771, 
136.582, 135.532, 123.974)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", 
"X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: (+1) I'm glad someone else posted a result so I could confirm

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do the whole operation at once.  This assumes you don't need to save the median, min, and max values for later.  If you do, please comment.

This function loops the three functions `median`, `min`, and `max` for a vector `x`, then sends the variables to the function environment, making them available to use by name in the `ifelse` and subsequent calculation.

```
index <- function(x, ...) {
    funs <- c(med = median, min = min, max = max)
    list2env(lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, ...)), environment())
    ifel <- ifelse(x < med, med - min, max - med)
    (x - med) / ifel * 100
}
```

Then we can use `sapply` or `lapply` or others to get the index values. Here I used `cbind` to avoid new assignment before I posted this.

```
indVals <- cbind(df[1:2], sapply(df[-c(1:2)], index, na.rm=TRUE))
indVals[,1:5]
#       X1       X2           X3          X4           X5
# 1 28.188 -111.438          NaN         NaN          NaN
# 2 28.188 -111.312  100.0000000  100.000000  100.0000000
# 3 28.188 -111.188   19.5253013   19.690246   19.7010032
# 4 28.188 -111.062   76.7090200   76.524161   76.3880913
# 5 28.188 -110.938   -8.6049493  -10.013107  -10.6078282
# 6 28.188 -110.812    0.4739999    0.473519    0.5177805
# 7 28.188 -110.688   -7.9056758   -8.082774   -8.9585261
# 8 28.188 -110.562  -17.2526320  -16.622314  -16.8912667
# 9 28.188 -110.438 -100.0000000 -100.000000 -100.0000000
```